# What stands for CMB in iTunes Connect Sales And Trends?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to know that stands for CMB in the iTunes Connect Sales And Trends report, I have looked at the guide and there's nothing specified.

Answer (score 4):

The "[iTunes Connect Sales and Trends Guide](http://help.apple.com/itc/appssalesandtrends/#/itc8d07eb5aa)" (available after clicking on the '?' mark in iTunes Connect) has some information you may have overlooked.

The glossary states that "CMB" is:

> Complete My Bundle (CMB) 
>   The action taken by a customer to purchase
>   the remaining apps in a bundle beyond those already purchased.

From the Sales Report section:

> If the transaction involves a “completed” app bundle, this field will
>   contain a value of “CMB.” App credits for completed bundles will show
>   a value of “CMB-C.” Otherwise this field is blank.

Answer (score 2):

I saw CMB in itunes report today, when I tried to search for answer, I stumbled upon this question.

Though Linus G. is helpful, I would like to add few more info which I read now in other site.

Bundle Completions (CMB)
A bundle completion occurs when a user that has already purchased an app that's also available in an App Bundle downloads the entire bundle. Because the App Bundle is sold at a discounted rate, several things are recorded for each bundle completion.

Source: https://appfigures.com/support/kb/529/how-are-app-bundles-tracked

Based on above information and few such scenario in my reports today, this is my observation, but I may be wrong.

Example:
1) Single app – “A” costs 1 USD.
2) App Bundle which has apps A + B + C and costs 2 USD.

When a user purchase app A for 1USD and later he purchase app bundle “A+B+C” for 2 USD, then system automatically returns back 1USD(cost of app A) to user.

In itunes report you would see CMB for Bundled App “A+B+C”

and

CMB-C for Single App “A” ( I presume C stands for credit, but not sure).

Hope this would be useful for anyone looking to know what is CMB in itunes reports.

Answer (score 0):

From iTunesConnect's user guide:

> If the transaction involves a "completed" app bundle then this field will contain a value of "CMB". App credits for completed bundles will show a value of "CMB-C". Otherwise this field is blank.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Don't know about the person who asked the question, but this didn't help me.